# Show helper text on clicking textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, textbox, focus, setfocus

I want to display helper text on clicking on the text boxes.
eg: If I click a text box it should help us by saying what to type: Enter username here

I have tried below given code but the text ***"Enter username"*** is fading out, I want the text to be displayed until the focus is changed to another text box.

please, suggest some code for this type.

```
<input type = "text"/><span>Enter username</span>
<input type = "text"/><span>Enter password</span>     


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focus(function () {
         $(this).next("span").css('display','inline').fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following should do it

```
$(function(){
    $("input")
        .focus(function () {
            $(this).next("span").fadeIn(1000);
        })
        .blur(function () {
             $(this).next("span").fadeOut(1000);
        }); 
});
```

Here is a  **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ewini)**

Comment: You can edit the sample by adding <b>/edit</b> to the URL. You could improve it by ensuring that the helper text for a textbox fades in after the helper text for another textbox has finished fading out. This would be simple using CSS classes

Comment: that should have come out /edit to the URL. I thought html markup was now operative in comments but looks like it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're manipulating the CSS display property as well as using fadeIn/fadeOut:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focus(function () {
         $(this).next("span").fadeIn(1000);
    }).blur(function() {
        $(this).next("span").fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```